# ActionBar Sherlock showing empty at top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock library in my project and everything was working fine until I tried to get my action bar only at the bottom of the screen and remove it from the top of the screen. What I want to have is the action bar only displayed at bottom.

After removing the upper part, this is what I am getting:

[image: My result after aplying the following code]

My code for the OnCreate method is:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mSherlock
            .setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);

    requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //my stuff
}
```

And my Activity in the manifest is:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.apps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```

So I want to know what I may be doing wrong. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can the following code in manifest file to display icon on the top of action bar

```
android:icon="@drawable/youriconimage" this sets your application icon and if you want to add logo on the tab of action bar use
android:logo="@drawable/yourlogoimage"
```

hope it will help you.